# setting up angular 6 base_url not pointing to root in NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, express, angular6, angular4-router

I need to set up my angular 6 project NOT pointing to root, but to /v3/, this is what I did,
1. change base href in index.html to "/v3"
2. start app using ng serve --base-href /v3/
Now it worked fine for dev server at http://localhost:4200/v3/
But now I need to config my nodeJS server to serve this also at http://localhost:3000/v3/
I tried to change the config in express like below:

```
app.get('/v3/*', (req,res)=>{
         res.sendfile('index.html', { root: path.resolve('../dv-ui/dist') } );
    })
```

this is to load the index.html, so if user point to http://localhost:3000/v3/, the index.html is up, but then whole page is blank.

i check the index.html, it still has:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.fa62713060e7012f88ea.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.9882b2aa34b57555e8ce.bundle.js">
```

so here,   the /v3/ is not automatically appended to the source. Also, I don't know how config node express to point to right place.

so I hope:
1. generated index,html should have /v3/ added automatidally to the css/js url; 2. config nodeJS server to serve file when the URL has /v3/ , because you can see from mty update, all the /v3/* is using index.html to serve, I don't it is correct

Thanks